# What is another term for "through osmosis"?

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a single word to replace the phrase "through osmosis" with a single term, if that's even the correct phrase...

Example:

> When my daughter's project won the science fair, I too felt pride through osmosis."

I don't mean it as a synonym for empathy, more like "your success is my success".

Thanks.

Comment: 'by proxy' or 'by association' might work.  Or 'I too felt a vicarious pride'.

Comment: [Osmosis](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/osmosis) isn't really the right word. Osmosis is, literally, a process by which substances move across semi-permeable membranes and, figuratively, a process by which someone learns something without conscious effort. The phrase you need is either 'by proxy' or 'by association' as suggested by @Balaz2ta above.

Comment: @BoldBen Strictly yes, but you've never heard it as a metaphor? Some people have some weird metaphors, but I generally let them have them. Also, it's in dictionaries as: 2. A gradual, often unconscious process of assimilation or absorption: learned French by osmosis while residing in Paris for 15 years. / 4. gradual or unconscious assimilation or adoption, as of ideas. - Not exactly the same thing but the idea is of absorbing of spreading knowledge or ideas. In the OP's context it's pride.

Comment: @Zebrafish Definitely Osmosis is  a good word and commonly used beyond cell talk.  It certainly has its place - but I think the problem here is that the process is not gradual or over time. It also feels a bit forced.

Comment: If you want to stick with "osmosis" as the metaphor, then "osmoticly" (see "osmotic") is a perfectly good word.

Comment: Why not just end your sentence after "pride"?

Comment: @HotLicks Surely _osmotically_?

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in a comment to the question, the adverb ***osmotically*** (see Merriam-Webster's definition of [*osmotic*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/osmotic)) is perfectly valid. So, if you are fine with the base word, then just use that.

---

If you want a different, single word, then my preference would be **vicariously**, also as mentioned in a comment.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*vicarious*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vicariously):

> **1** : experienced or realized through imaginative or sympathetic participation in the experience of another
>   // a *vicarious* thrill

So, your sentence could take one of these forms:

> When my daughter's project won the science fair, I felt pride vicariously.
>   When my daughter's project won the science fair, I felt a vicarious pride.

---

Note that I removed the word *too*.

I am assuming that you mean to say that your daughter feels pride—and so do you. But if you say *I too felt pride vicariously*, that would mean you felt pride vicariously just as somebody else (your daughter) felt pride vicariously. However, your daughter's pride is *not* vicarious, it's direct. So, the *too* provides an unintended meaning.

Or you may actually have meant to use *too* but left out some other information:

> As the other parents felt with their children, when my daughter's project won the science fair, I too felt pride vicariously.

Now it can be understood that you are joining the other parents in feeling pride vicariously.

Answer (score 0):

> When my daughter's project won the science fair, I too felt pride ***surrogately***.

> surrogately
>  adj.
> 1.By means of a substitute; by proxy.
>  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/surrogately)

Comment: I hope I only get upvoted

Comment: You misspelled surrogately. (-1).... Just kidding, I think it's a creative answer. Hope you don't mind me editing the spelling. Also added a reference, that's a good idea too.